# Android: How to put Path object into Bundle?

Tags: android, path, bundle, parcelable

I would like to put into Bundle for example Path object. I know, that I can use putParcelable(), but argument of this function should implement Parcelable interface. I tried to make another class which inherits Path and implements Parcelable, but I don't have idea how to implement Parcelable's functions.

Do you have any idea how to put Path object into Bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make your class `extend Path` and `implement serializable`. Then you can just call `putSerializable()` to pass in the `Path` object.